# PostgreSQL UNION between Integer and JSONB get error : UNION types integer and jsonb cannot be matched

Tags: sql, postgresql, union-all

I want to merge 2 table into one by using **UNION ALL** operator.
The first table has several fields. The second table groups several field into on JSONB field.

In order to simplify the question, I **reproduced the error** by using this simple SQL request (without any dependance on table) :

```
SELECT 10 as price  
    UNION ALL 
SELECT '{"price":2}'::jsonb->'price' as price;
```

This request return the following error :

```
ERROR:  UNION types integer and jsonb cannot be matched
LINE 3: SELECT '{"price":2}'::jsonb->'price' as price;
```

How can I merge an integer with JSONB interger property by using UNION ALL operator ?

I want to get the following output :

```
 price
-------
    10
     2
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON seems so simple and yet it gets a bit complicated when working with types.  You want to extract the *element* as a value; then, you can convert to an integer.  Hence:

```
SELECT 10 as price  
UNION ALL 
SELECT ('{"price":2}'::jsonb->>'price')::int as price
```

Comment: Thank you it works. I will accept your answer when I can.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator returns a JSONB value, not an integer. You need to use the `->>` operator which returns a `text` and then cast that to an integer:

```
SELECT 10 as price  
    UNION ALL 
SELECT ('{"price":2}'::jsonb->>'price')::int as price;
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It works and parenthesis are required.